# On click of child div having same class as its parent some class should be added to child div not parent div

Tags: jquery

I have following html structure.

```
<div class="someclass">
   <div class="someclass"></div>
</div>
```

So when I click on child div "someclass" some other class say "test" should be added to it but that class should not be added to parent `div.someclass` and if I click on parent div then "test" class should be added to parent div not to child div

Comment: `$('.someclass .someclass').click(function(e) {..})`

Comment: Use a descendant selector to select the element and the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Working Demo**

```js
$(".someclass").children().click(function(){
    $(this).addClass('red');
})
```

```css
.red{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="someclass">Parent
   <div class="someclass">Child</div>
</div>
```

**OR**

```
$(".someclass > .someclass").click(function(){
```

**OR**

```
$('.someclass .someclass').click(function() {
```

---

Comment: Thanks dude. It is so simple.